# An apex method that accepts a sentence and return the number of spaces in it

Tags: apex

Can you guys help me with this question.
An apex method that accepts a sentence and return the number of spaces in it

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`String.countMatches()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_countMatches) method, which:

> Returns the number of times the specified substring occurs in the current String.

For instance:

```
String lorem = 'Lorem ipsum is a dummy text used to replace text';
lorem.countMatches(' '); // 9
```

Comment: Of course, this won't handle tabs and other forms of whitespace, plus isn't related to the number of words as you could have sequences of multiple spaces or whitespace characters between words...

Comment: It's not a method though. I can't pass it via a class, and then call it through the Execute anonymous window. Help please.

Comment: My class:public class numspace {
 String sentence='Hello World';
}                                                                                                                               
 Esecute anonymous window: numspace np = new numspace();

System.debug(numspace.countMatches(' '));

Comment: I recommend you start out with the [apex trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database). There's plenty of information available about how to write Apex if you search.

Comment: BTW, this is a method, but the method exists on String, not your custom apex class.